# Remove more than 1 period in String - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a simple string. In this string, I can have any number. Sometimes this number has more than 1 period. My goal is to remove more than 1 period so if I take a for example it should look like this = 20.00011. How can I do this?

```py
import re

a = "20.00.0.11"
a_replaced = re.sub(r'\.+', ".", a)


print(a_replaced)
```

Comment: has it to be regex?

Comment: I don't have to use regex. This is what I tried. If this problem can be fixed with plain python - even better

Comment: "We have a problem." "It's ok, I know regex." "Now we have two problems."

Comment: The problem is that `r'\.+'` matches one or more periods **in a row**. Regex by itself won't solve your problem since you need to keep track of the first period found and remove all the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
a = "20.00.0.11"

t = a.split('.')  #breaks the item into token
t[0]+'.'+''.join(t[1:]) #join them back with a single .
```

```
'20.00011'
```

If incase you have all possibilities where you may have multiple .'s or a single one or no .'s then you can use the following function -

```
a = "20.00.0.11"
b = "20.000"
c = "20000"

def fix_dots(a):
    t = a.split('.')
    if len(t)>1:
        return t[0]+'.'+''.join(t[1:])
    else:
        return t[0]
```

```
print(fix_dots(a))
#Output - '20.00011'

print(fix_dots(b))
#Output - '20.000'

print(fix_dots(c))
#Output - '20000'
```

The list comprehension way of solving this is by using finding the location of the first dot and then using a OR condition to keep that dot and ignore other dots.

```
a = "20.00.0.11"

def fix_dot2(a):
    return ''.join([i[1] for i in enumerate(a) if i[0]==a.find('.') or i[1]!='.'])

print(fix_dot2(a))
```

```
'20.00011'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"".join("20.00.0.11".replace(".","!",1).split(".")).replace("!",".")
```

Alternatively:

```
string = "20.00.0.11"
dot = string.find(".")
"".join([x for (i, x) in enumerate(string) if (x != ".") | (i==dot)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be splitting up by ".",  and make sure to add exactly one back at the second index of the list.

```
a = "20.00.0.11"
lst = a.split('.')
lst.insert(1, '.')
a_replaced = ''.join(lst)

print(a_replaced)
>>> "20.00011"
```

Using this version will give you a more compressed one line code:

```
a = "20.00.0.11"
a_replaced = ''.join(a.split('.').insert(1, '.'))
```

---

This solution assumes that the input first period is the period you want to keep.

Also if there are no periods in the input, one will be added at the end of the string. If you don't want this, you will need to add one if check.